# Compositing and motion tracking the object is bright but see through

Tags: compositing-nodes

The object will end up transparent but I don't know how to explain it.

[image]

This is a compositing issue I have tried using a mix node and aplha over node with different FAC values and get a product worse or the same.
[image]
[The file google drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BIiOMknQf6Jev9eroUo-9BvZlz-_Apje?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a properly encoded RGBA buffer, the RGB represents the quantity of emission of a given pixel "window", and the A represents the degree of occlusion of the geometry.

The proper approach here is to simply take your rendered image and apply an Alpha Over your background, at a "full" 1.0 factor.